# how to set command line parameter to BSON::Timestamp

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Pls advice how to set command line parameter`tail_from` which will be accepted by below code:

```
def optail
  tail_from = options[:tail_from]
  if tail_from.is_a? Time
    tail_from = tailer.most_recent_position(tail_from)
  end
  tailer.tail(:from => tail_from, :filter => options[:oplog_filter])
  ...
end
```

It suggested to be Unix Timestamp
but task fails with error:

`For mongo databases, tail :from must be a BSON::Timestamp  Mongoriver::Assertions::AssertionFailure)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BSON::Timestamp from a Unix timestamp using its [constructor](https://api.mongodb.com/bson-ruby/current/BSON/Timestamp.html#initialize-instance_method), setting the increment to 0.

Also, the change streams' functionality has been expanded in recent releases and instead of using an oplog tailer you should consider [database or cluster level change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-change-streams/#watching-for-changes-on-a-database).

Comment: thanks Oleg,
but more interesting question for me is - how to pass Unix timestamp over command line parameter?

Comment: It's just a number.